# Clustering Distance Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, classification

I have a list of words an a numeric value for each group of words.
The same word is written sometimes incorrectly in my database, so if "dog" has the numeric value "120", I also want to assign the same numeric value to a misspelling like "dogg".

My idea so far was to use the Levenshtein distance to calculate a distance matrix for the words, which I have done now in Matlab. My questions: Which methods would be best now to cluster my (obviously symmetric) distance matrix, and as a final step being able to predict for a new dataset of words which numeric value can be assigned to them?

Comment: the simplest way is to decide on a minimal distance that you accept as a "legitimate typo" and then threshold your distance matrix according to that distance. Based on the resulting binary matrix, you can extract clusters based on the connected components of the induced graph.